# Django/Python : Sort python's dictionaries with the equals key

Tags: python, django, sorting, dictionary

I am currently trying to sort two Python dictionaries into an HTML array such as:

```
#Headers
DictA = {'value': 'valeur', 'name': 'nom' }

#Data
DictB = {'value': '456', 'name': 'Test' }
```

I wanted to sort these two dictionaries in order to get the `'456'` in `DictB` equals to the key `'value'` in `DictA`.

Note: I used other dictionaries than `DictA` and `DictB`, it was just an example. But it fits my problem.

In my `views.py`, I define my two dictionaries such as:

```
headers = json.loads(entries[0].form_data_headers)

data = json.loads(entries[1].saved_data)  
valuesData = data.values()
```

then I pass them into the `template.html` via the context:

```
context = {'entries': entries, 'form_entry_id': form_entry_id, 'headers': headers, 'data': data, 'valuesData': valuesData}
```

Thus, in my template, it will print an array with the headers (`DictA`) and the datas (`DictB`).

In my template I make this code:

```
 <thead>
            <!-- Test pr voir si les values sont pris en compte ou non -->
            <p>{{valuesData}}</p>
            <tr>
            {% for entry in headers %}
            <td>
            {{ entry }}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>                 
         </thead>
```

And the datas are in another `for` loop:

```
<tbody>
 <thead>
            <!-- Test pr voir si les values sont pris en compte ou non -->
            <p>{{valuesData}}</p>
            <tr>
            {% for entry in dataValues %}
            <td>
            {{ entry }}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>                 
         </thead>
</tbody>
```

The result is kinda such as follow:

- name equals 456 (instead of the name of the form)
- geom equals test (instead of my coordinate)

etc.

It doesn't match the right header.

I was thinking about making two `for` loops with an `if` statement in it:

```
{%if headers['name'] == dataValues['name']%}
<td>dataValues['name']</td>
```

But I get an error as `dataValues['name']` could not be parsed.

The rest of the code is in Javascript:

```
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetURLParameter(param_name){
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var sParameterName = sPageURL.split('=');
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
        var name= GetURLParameter(name);
        document.querySelector('.page-header .value').innerHTML = name;
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block main-content-inner-attrs %}
{% endblock main-content-inner-attrs %}

{% block sidebar-wrapper %}
{% endblock sidebar-wrapper %}
```

---

The rest of the code is in javascript :

```
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetURLParameter(param_name){
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var sParameterName = sPageURL.split('=');
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
        var name= GetURLParameter(name);
        document.querySelector('.page-header .value').innerHTML = name;
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block main-content-inner-attrs %}
{% endblock main-content-inner-attrs %}

{% block sidebar-wrapper %}
{% endblock sidebar-wrapper %}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)? i.e. `dataValues.update(headers)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right answer :

```
<tr>
                  {% for cle, valeur in headersLoop %}
                  {% for cleVD, valeurVD in valuesData %}
                  {% if cle == cleVD %}
                  <td>
                  <p> {{cle}}{{valeurVD}} </p>
                  </td>

                  {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </tr>
```

I marked it as solved. And create a new topic. Thanks all.