# Django/Python : How to fill my html array with all datas from fobi's forms

Tags: python, django, dictionary

From my previous post here [First Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033957/django-python-sort-pythons-dictionaries-with-the-equals-key?noredirect=1#comment77065577_45033957) that i solved, i need to fill an html array with all the datas included in my forms.

I work with Django/Fobi and use Python/html.

In my Views.py, i declare my variable to get the headers of my form and the data such as :

```
entries = SavedFormDataEntry._default_manager \
                            .filter(user__pk=request.user.pk) \
                            .select_related('form_entry')

 headers = json.loads(entries[0].form_data_headers)

 headersLoop = headers.items()

data = json.loads(entries[1].saved_data)  
valuesData = data.items()
```

Then i add these variables into the context:

```
    context = {'entries': entries, 'form_entry_id': form_entry_id, 'headers': headers, 'data': data, 'valuesData': valuesData,'headersLoop': headersLoop}
```

After that, these datas are sent to the template.html where i made this loop :

```
<tr>
                  {% for cle, valeur in headersLoop %}
                  {% for cleVD, valeurVD in valuesData %}
                  {% if cle == cleVD %}
                  <td>
                  <p> {{cle}}{{valeurVD}} </p>
                  </td>

                  {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </tr>
```

And it prints the headers which match to the right data.

As you can see in this picture :
[image]

From my code with entries[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033957/django-python-sort-pythons-dictionaries-with-the-equals-key?noredirect=1#comment77065577_45033957), i only take one form in order to fill my array.

I just want to know if there is a way to take all the entries such as:
 #Taking all the datas in saved_data
`

```
`data = json.loads(entries[all].saved_data)`
```

`In order to fill all the array like (with my 13 forms ) it shows in the picture. It only prints 1 of my form for the moment.

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: It is not clear at all what are you trying to do. Please update the question with example data in `entries` and the expected result. Also, please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a way that minimizes the time and effort for someone who tries to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are trying to use the `entries` queryset (over `SavedFormDataEntry` model) in your template.

Too iterate over it with [`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for) in Django template, it doesn't have to be a dictionary, querysets work also, just fetch the results first (with `all()`):

```
entries = SavedFormDataEntry._default_manager \
                            .filter(user__pk=request.user.pk) \
                            .select_related('form_entry').all()
```

In template:

```
<ul>
{% for entry in entries %}
    <li>{{ entry.saved_data }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. Indeed i want each entry matches each header properly. But i can only take one entry (such as entries[1].saved_data). I cannot take all the entries in a same time.  I want to print all the entries.saved_data to match properly the header such as (header 'name ' -> name of the entries.saved_data for all the forms), and so on with the other header.

Comment: Why are you pairing headers from `entries[0]` with `saved_data` from `entries[1]`? What's the logic behind that? How would you pair it for all (other) entries?

Comment: I pair headers from entries[0] to only get the name, geom, value element and print them in the top of my array. Then, i wanted to test if i can pair it with saved_data from entries with one form created. That's work pretty good. But indeed, i can't pair it for all other entries and i'm stuck with that...  I just want to get one row with the headers ( already done and checked ) and antoher row with all the datas paired to their right headers .